# How can i split up a text file by paragraph?

Tags: python, split

I have a text file and basically its a bunch of characters that im going to do stuff to but I've been having trouble spliting it.

it looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 

15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37

39 40
41 42
```

I want to split it by "paragraph" and then from there by each line. I know how to read the function and everything, but everything I've been trying hasn't been working, like doing split('\n\n'). Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you do `split('\n\n')` ?

Comment: i just get all the numbers all together in one string with '\n' in it. it's weird

Comment: read the whole file and then do `split('\n\n')` like `filobj.read().split('\n\n')`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually much simpler than you are making it:

```
10. Read each line in and append them together as long 
    as the next line is not empty. 
    When you do encounter a blank line, 
    split the current "paragraph" with ` `.

20. Goto 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this look like what you want:

```
txt=open("nums.txt").read()
[[x for x in ilist if len(x) > 0] for ilist in map(lambda x : x.split("\n"),txt.split("\n\n"))]
```

`[['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ', '9 10 11 12 13 14 '], ['15 16 17 18 19 20', '21 22 23 24 25 26 27', '28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37'], ['39 40', '41 42']]`

If you want them all as integers then :

```
map (lambda x : map(lambda x :reduce (lambda z,y: z+[int(y)] if y.isdigit() else z,x.split(),[]),x),[[x for x in ilist if len(x) > 0] for ilist in map(lambda x : x.split("\n"),txt.split("\n\n"))])
```

which gives O/P:

`[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]], [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]], [[39, 40], [41, 42]]]`